# Resize an image on upload then move_upload_file function

Tags: javascript, php, image, file, upload

Is there any way to resize the `$_FILES["xfile1"]["tmp_name"]` before I send it off to the `move_uploaded_file()` function? I checked everywhere but nobody seems to use this function after resizing the image.

```
// Create image from file
switch(strtolower($_FILES['xfile1']['type']))
{
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['xfile1']['tmp_name']);
    break;
    case 'image/png':
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['xfile1']['tmp_name']);
    break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['xfile1']['tmp_name']);
    break;
    default:
        exit('Unsupported type: '.$_FILES['xfile1']['type']);
}

// Delete original file
@unlink($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

// Target dimensions
$max_width = 540;
$max_height = 540;

// Get current dimensions
$old_width = imagesx($image);
$old_height = imagesy($image);

// Calculate the scaling we need to do to fit the image inside our frame
$scale = min($max_width/$old_width, $max_height/$old_height);

// Get the new dimensions
$new_width = ceil($scale*$old_width);
$new_height = ceil($scale*$old_height);

 // Create new empty image
$new = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

 // Resample old into new
 imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 
  $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);

  ob_start();
  imagejpeg($new,'saved.jpeg' , 90);
  $data = ob_get_clean();
```

So i have this so far. I have this `$data` variable which i want to replace with `$_FILES["xfile1"]["tmp_name"]` in the `move_uploaded_file()` function. Is that possible?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you do it the other way around? Start with is_uploaded_file()? If so, shrink from tmp. Delete tmp. Save wherever without move_uploaded_file.

Comment: `imagejpeg($new,'saved.jpeg' , 90);` will actually create the copy on disk, there's not really any need to use `move_uploaded_file()` afterwards. You could put in a check for `is_uploaded_file()` though, just in case.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` is a sandbox function.Due to security concerns you cannot access uploaded file in anyway unless you call this function (you may search in your tmp path but that's another thing)